# ¿Puede ser utilizada la palabra «mono» como sinónimo de «simio»?

Tags: traducción, sinónimos

Richard Dawkins twiteó:

> English has different words for ape and monkey. Interestingly, most European languages don’t, and that’s surprising given that biologists make rather heavy weather of the distinction. No doubt replies will mention other languages that make the distinction.

[image: Richard Dawkins's tweet]

Una de las respuestas con más *likes* fue:

> The first one, in Spanish: simio / mono

Sin embargo *creo* que en español las dos palabras son intercambiables. Como prueba el libro de Desmond Morris: *The Naked Ape* fue traducido al español como *El Mono Desnudo*

[image: el libro de Desmond Morris The Naked Ape fue traducido al español como El Mono Desnudo]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Son intercambiables las palabras **mono** y **simio**?

Comment: Just to note: in English, monkey can also mean any non-human primate, including apes: ["Chimpanzees are known to form bands to hunt and kill other monkeys."](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/27164529/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/hippie-apes-have-dark-side-too/) (NBC Live Science, 2008). Though this use is a bit antiquated now, and normally considered colloquial or informal.

Comment: Yo "monkey" lo traduciría como "chango".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Miremos a las definiciones del DLE:

> #### mono, na
>
> De mona, y este quizá acort. de maimona, f. de maimón 'mico'.
>
> ...
>
> 5. m. y f. Animal del suborden de los simios. U. en m. ref. a la especie.
>
> ...
>
> 12. f. Mamífero cuadrumano de unos 60 cm de altura, con pelaje de color pardo amarillento, grandes abazones, nalgas sin pelo y callosas, y cola muy corta, que se cría en África y en el peñón de Gibraltar, y se domestica fácilmente.

> #### simio, simia
>
> Del lat. simius; la forma f., del lat. simia.
>
> 1. m. y f. Primate antropoide. U. t. c. m. pl. como taxón.

Así que, (tradicionalmente) mono es un sinónimo de simio, pero también se puede referir específicamente a una especia de mono de Gibraltar.

Eso dicho, Wikipedia nota esto:

> Los términos mono y simio son sinónimos, pero en la zoología suele hacerse una distinción entre ambos, debido a una influencia del idioma inglés, en el que los términos equivalentes monkey y ape tienen diferentes significados.
>
> - https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono

Comment: A esto sólo le agregaría que, si bien *mono* y *simio* son sinónimos, *simio* es un término más bien técnico/formal en español. Esto de por así hace que no sean intercambiables en todas las circunstancias.